# Troubles with WADL / generated XSD using Jersey with a contract-first approach

Tags: java, xsd, jersey, wadl, contract-first

I have been working on a REST web service using Jersey for a few days now, and managed to have all CRUD operations working, with several exchange formats: XML, JSON, Google Protobuf.

However I am facing some issues related to automatically generated WADL and XSD.

---

## Context

To define the objects exchanged in these three formats, I have followed a **"contract-first" approach**:

- from a XSD I wrote, I generated my model classes using JAXB;
- from an equivalent proto file I wrote, I generated the Google Protobuf classes (and internally have a way to convert these to the JAXB-generated objects, in order to have one unique model).

However, as I would like my users to be able to **generate their classes** too, I would like to share these schema files (.xsd and .proto) and have them **well integrated with the automatically generated WADL**.

For that purpose, thanks to [this](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/HowToConfigureExtendedWADL) wiki page:

- I have exposed the two files under

  - `/schema/schema.xsd`
  - `/schema/schema.proto`
- I have added an application-grammar file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <grammars xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XML/xinclude">
      <include href="../schema/schema.xsd" />
  </grammars>
  ```
- I have added a customized WADL generator:

  ```
   public class RichWadlGeneratorConfig extends WadlGeneratorConfig {
      @Override
      public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {
          return generator(WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.class)
              .prop("applicationDocsStream", "application-doc.xml")
              .generator(WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.class)
              .prop("grammarsStream", "application-grammars.xml")
              .descriptions();
      }
   }
  ```

This way the below appears in the WADL, when I hit `/rest/application.wadl`:

```
<grammars>
     <include href="../schema/schema.xsd"/>
     <include href="application.wadl/xsd0.xsd">
          <doc title="Generated" xml:lang="en"/>
     </include>
</grammars>
```

---

## Problem

`/rest/application.wadl/xsd0.xsd` is automatically generated from my classes, but is quite **different** from what I initially had in `schema.xsd`.
In addition to that, calling a tool like `wadl2java` on this WADL fails miserably, presumably because

- `/schema/schema.xsd`, and
- `/rest/application.wadl/xsd0.xsd`

are now conflicting (two definitions for the same objects).

---

## Questions

1. Is there a way to disable the generation and diffusion of this automatically generated XSD? 
   (As I don't need it since I'm following this "contract-first" approach)
2. If not, is there a way to "override" its content with my manually written XSD when `/rest/application.wadl/xsd0.xsd` is hit?
   (I have googled around and found about WadlResource, to generate customized WADL, but found nothing about the XSD generation itself)

---

Thanks in advance for your help!

M.

---

## Edit

1) I raised the issue to the Jersey team and got a reply:
http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2012-06/message/8

2) I raised a ticket (JERSEY-1230), according to Pavel's instructions.
I am currently following up to either submit a fix myself or get a fix from the Jersey team.

Comment: issue is fixed now, see http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1230

Comment: you should post the above as an answer to your own question and then accept it (to clear it from the unanswered Q's list).

Answer (score 1):

[1.14-SNAPSHOT](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1230) should allow you to do this:

```
public class SampleWadlGeneratorConfig extends WadlGeneratorConfig {

    @Override
    public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {
        return generator( WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.class )
                .prop( "applicationDocsStream", "application-doc.xml" )
                .generator( WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.class )
                .prop( "grammarsStream", "application-grammars.xml" )
                .prop("overrideGrammars", true)                               // !!!
                .generator( WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class )
                .prop( "resourceDocStream", "resourcedoc.xml" )
                .descriptions();
    }

}
```

when overrideGrammars is set to true, Jersey generated grammars won't be included in returned WADL.