# In Jersey, how do I specify a minimal application.wadl that only shows resources?

Tags: java, jersey, war, wadl

For example, I want something of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM" />
    <grammars />
    <resources base="https://localhost/plugh/">
    ....
    </resources>
/application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question to share what I learned.

Define a subclass of WadlGeneratorConfig,
where you define a WadlGenerator grammar that does nothing.

```
  package com.try1234;


  import java.util.List;

  import com.sun.jersey.api.wadl.config.WadlGeneratorConfig;
  import com.sun.jersey.api.wadl.config.WadlGeneratorDescription;
  import com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport;

  public class PlughWadlGeneratorConfig extends WadlGeneratorConfig
  {
      @Override
      public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure()
      {
          return
           generator(WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.class)
               .prop("grammarsStream", "application-grammars.xml")
               .prop("overrideGrammars", true)
           .descriptions();
      }
  }
```

Define an empty application-grammars.xml

```
<grammars xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XML/xinclude">
</grammars>
```

Make sure it is on the classpath for the webapp, e.g., in a Maven-style directory structure, the file resides in target/classes.

Modify your web.xml to use the subclass of WadlGeneratorConfig. Add these lines:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WadlGeneratorConfig</param-name>
    <param-value>com.try1234.PlughWadlGeneratorConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Load your web application, the following GET on this URL should work:

https://localhost/plugh/application.wadl

This solution works for Jersey 1.18.

Note: The rationale for the empty grammars element is that
I had run into https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-411 ; by not producing any , I was able to avoid the IllegalArgumentException.

References:
http://razvancaraghin.blogspot.com/2014/01/html-documentation-for-your-rest.html

[Troubles with WADL / generated XSD using Jersey with a contract-first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870583/troubles-with-wadl-generated-xsd-using-jersey-with-a-contract-first-approach)